# Apply autocomplete to dynamically generated textboxes with data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, input

I have gone through many ques here on stackoverflow with regard to my query here but could not apply them to my problem.

Hence I am giving here my files that I have been using.

I am successfully able to use autocomplete with a static textbox. I get the data from the database. But however I am not able to figure out how to do it for dynamically generated textboxes. I want autocomplete feature to be implemented for dynamically generated textboxes with data from databases

here are my files:

index.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Auto Complete Input box</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true
});
 });
 </script>

  <script>
   function addForm(){
  $("#forms").append(
    "<form><input type ='text' name='winner' id='winner'><br/></form>"
   );
 }
  </script>
 </head>

  <body>
  <label>Name:</label>
   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="20"/>
   <input type="button" name="addmore" id="addmore" value="Add More Winners" onclick="addForm();"/>
<div id = "dyanamic"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

autocomplete.php

```
  <?php
require 'config.php';
$q=$_GET['q'];
$my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
//$mysqli=mysql_connect('localhost','root','','emp_db') or die("Database Error");
$sql="SELECT name FROM employee WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if($result)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['name']."\n";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Where are you adding text inputs?

Comment: @tymeJV:
I have updated my code to show how I am adding the textboxes..

Comment: When you add your new element to the DOM with jQuery, give the new text field an ID and then use the same method ($("#element_id").autocomplete...). What's the problem?

Comment: @Sébastien: I have updated my code aboce to show how I add textboxes. I do not exactly know how to use autocomplete for dyanamic textboxes. Further I want to save all the data added by uder in these boxes to the database. I am confused

Answer (score 2):

Just call your `.autocomplete()` function on your newly added inputs AFTER they have been added to the DOM

```
function addForm() {
    $("#forms").append("<form><input type ='text' name='winner' id='winner'><br/></form>");
    $("#winner").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked now.. :) but it works for only one dyanamix text box and not for the third and so on.. How to change the above code?

Comment: @SeeyaK -- You need to learn how jQuery selectors work, the above only targets the newly added element with ID of `winner`. Change that to accomodate any new ones.

Comment: Yes I was trying to add something like a variable counter. May be it is a stupid idea. Yes I need to learn jQuery but I needed a quick solution since it was a bit urgent. Could you tell me how to go about it?

Comment: Hi.. I used class instead of id and now it works. But I will need to check later if it works fine when I add more code. Thnks for suggesting me to use jQuery selectors. I will ask for help from u if I get more difficulties in future

Comment: one ques..even though now it works wen i use class instd of id,how shud i go about if i want to access each of these elements using $_POST in php?

Comment: @SeeyaK -- Class was definitely the right approach. As for accessing them, you're going to have to serialize the data most likely, give a different `name` attribute to each.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Jquery selectors. yeah I was trying to give different name attrbute to each textbox but I do not know how. I was thinking of appending a counter variable to the name attribute: ex name='test+i' where I keep incrementing 'i'. But I do not understand how to do it since I am newboe in javascript n jQuery.

Comment: Can You suggest me a way to go about this?

Comment: @SeeyaK -- It really all depends on how you send your data back, but one way would be in a `for` loop, set the `name` attribute to something like `"<input type='text' name='textbox'" + i + "' />`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38114/discussion-between-seeya-k-and-tymejv)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put the init code ($('#id').autocomplete) for autocompletion on the js code part that update your page dynamically. I guess you're using ajax, so you should have someting like that

```
$.ajax({
    // your ajax options here
}).done(
    // here you update your html page
    // and then set the autocomplete on the new element
)
```